# Create a (Windows type) Instance of an application in Linux

Tags: wine, application

The background:

I have some old Windows Applications that I need to get running in a Wine environment on Linux. I have got to the point where I can start the application and it runs fine. However I can only run one copy of the application at a time.

The Problem:

In Windows, I can run multiple copies of these applications by creating 'instances' of them. e.g. I **create a shortcut**, then **right click** > **properties** and in the **target window** I add an instance name to the end. (e.g. `c:\folder\myApp.exe test1` creates an instance called `test1`).

In the background each **instance** creates it's own entries in the windows registry which I guess allows it to function independently of the main application.

Is there a way of doing something similar in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to create a new WINEPREFIX.

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-new
wine winecfg
```

You can then reference the application using that prefix:

```
WINEPREFIX="~/.wine-new" wine myapp.exe
```

Comment: Why not just `wine myapp.exe test1`?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't appear to work. `WINEPREFIX="~/.wine" wine myapp.exe test1`. Without `test1`, the app opens. With `test1`, nothing.